# How to pass passwords with space for curl command

Tags: bash, rest, shell, curl

I have password something like this "Example Password0=" for a rest call.

I have tried:

```
curl -u $username:$password -XGET url
curl -u $username:"$password" -XGET url
```

Both didn't work. How can I pass this password with space to curl command in script?

Comment: How about `"$usermame:$password"`?

Comment: Are you sure `password` was set correctly in the first place? The second should work fine (assuming you correct the `usermame` typo).

Comment: @oguzismail I tried that but its giving curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Password0=; Unknown error. And this is in curl command and I am not sure why its taking password as two separate words even after enclosing it in double quotes.

Comment: @chepner Yes I verified the api using postman. Its working fine

Comment: @Miffy I don't know what that means or how it applies to the code you've shown.

Comment: The problem seems to be in $username, can you paste result of `od -An -t a  <<< "$username"` ?

Comment: It looks to me like there's a space (or something similar) at the end of the `username` variable. Check its exact value as @Philippe suggested (`declare -p username` is another good way to check). Also, you should enclose *all* variables in double-quotes, not just the ones you expect to contain weird characters (i.e. use `-u "$username:$password"` instead of `-u $username:"$password"` or `-u $username:$password`) -- that won't solve this particular problem, but it'll make the symptom match the actual problem (and maybe prevent other problems down the road).

Comment: @Philippe there is no space in username

Comment: Can you try this command : `curl -u "$username:$password" -XGET http://www.google.com` ?

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completion (and for the sake of future me looking up the answer again, because that's how I roll), there's nothing mysterious with spaces in credentials. They just need to be quoted:

```
curl -u "some username with spaces:some password with spaces" https://....
```

works just fine.